# The definite article in "That's the guy who dropped me into the lake"

Tags: definite-article

In a Spiderman movie, Spiderman gets into a fight with a villain. During the fight, the villain drops Spiderman into a lake. The next day, Spiderman in his civilian suit talks to his friend in school and during the conversation, they notice a strange man walking down the school hallway. Spiderman recognizes the man and tells his friend: "That's the guy who dropped me into the lake". His friend replied: "You got dropped into a lake?" How could Spiderman use the definite article before telling his friend someone dropped him into the lake?

Answer (score 1):

On a pragmatic level, it's unexpected that an important piece of new information—like having been dropped into a lake—would be buried in a relative clause, which makes this a humorous bit of dialogue.

Grammatically, it's a perfectly ordinary sentence pattern for identifying something—saying (specific thing or individual being pointed out) *is* (definite noun phrase description distinguishing that individual from everybody else):

- That's **the one I was telling you about**.
- He's **the actor I am most eager to meet**.
- Spiderman is **my favorite character**.
- The woman over there is **the owner of the company**.

Definiteness in English is used for many different reasons. One reason is to convey that a phrase refers to a unique individual. If Spiderman had used the indefinite article:

- That's **a** guy who dropped me into the lake.

it might be interpreted as implying that there were multiple guys who dropped him into the lake, and this was just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your response (*how come this event wasn't mentioned before*) is the same as the friend's response ("You got dropped into a lake?").

Like you, the friend is effectively saying: "[You're expecting me to know what you're talking about, but I didn't know that] you got dropped in a lake."

This should show you that, happily, your understanding of definite article usage matches a native English speaker's, in this case.  We would not expect this kind of sentence ("That's the guy") to introduce entirely new information.  Ordinarily, we would expect one of these two scenarios:

"Yesterday, some guy dropped me in a lake...[later]...Hey, that's the guy who dropped me in the lake!"

or

"That guy dropped me in the lake yesterday!"

In other words, in this kind of sentence, there's no choice between the definite article and the indefinite/no article; there's the choice of "that is the guy" or "that guy".  *That guy* is definite - you could substitute "the guy standing there" - but this kind of phrase can be used to introduce new information about the subject.  *That is the guy* should not introduce new information, except to identify which guy was previously being discussed.

There isn't really a way to make this sentence work with an indefinite article.  "That is a guy who dropped me in a lake" is not idiomatic.  If multiple people dropped you into a lake, you could say, "That is one of the guys who dropped me in the lake."  But not that this sentence also uses "the guys," so like the original sentence, it should refer to information that had previously been shared.